# ReactiveMongo retrieving return value of findAndUpdate

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

Using the previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35548420/get-the-return-value-of-reactivemongo-findandupdate-function) for ReactiveMongo 0.12.0 (`"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.12.0"`) and Play 2.5.10.

The code updates the MongoDB document perfectly but never returns the value from the database. Have tried various ways, but `findAndUpdate` never returns a value. Appreciate any help.

```
@Singleton
//class Counters extends Controller with MongoController {
class Counters @Inject()(val reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends Controller with MongoController with ReactiveMongoComponents {  

def collection: JSONCollection = db.collection[JSONCollection]("counters")
def collectionBSON: BSONCollection = db.collection[BSONCollection]("counters")   

def incrementCounter(name: String):Future[Option[Long]] =  {
      import reactivemongo.api.collections.bson.BSONBatchCommands.FindAndModifyCommand.FindAndModifyResult   

      implicit val reader = Macros.reader[Counter]


      val resultFut: Future[FindAndModifyResult] = collectionBSON.findAndUpdate(
        BSONDocument("name" -> COUNTER_NAME),
        BSONDocument("$inc" -> BSONDocument("seq" -> 5)),
        fetchNewObject = true,
        upsert = true
      )
      //resultFut.map(_.result[Counter])

      val updatedCountOpt = resultFut.map { r =>
        r.result[Counter].map { p =>
          println("=====inside Counters.scala p.seq=" + p.seq)
          p.seq
        }
      }

      updatedCountOpt
  }
```

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the spec where findAndUpdate is tested to be applied as expected: https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/blob/master/driver/src/test/scala/FindAndModifySpec.scala#L44

Comment: I have tried many different ways including the link above using c.runCommand(FindAndModify(jack, upsertOp)). In all cases the data in the database updated and counter incremented. However the data is never returned to the code from neither findAndUpdate nor FindAndModify.